# Write undefined number of form data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying now for a while to wrap my head around the following:

I've got a form that submits a user defined number of values to a PHP script and I need to write them into a MySQL database.

The form itself is working fine and `print_r()` shows my values like this:

```
[items] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [option] => 3
                        [check_1] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [option] => 2
                        [check_1] => 1
                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [check_1] => 1
                        [check_3] => 1
                    )

            )
```

There will be one option value and up to ten checkboxes per item. Now I'd need to end up with something like this to write each item to the DB:

```
INSERT INTO table (item_id, option, check_1, check_2,...) 
VALUES ('$ItemID', '$OptionValue', '$Check_1_Value', '$Check_2_Value',...)
```

My biggest problem is to read out the Item IDs (1,2 and 17 in this case) and get it into variables.

Comment: Did you miss an `[option] => ?` from that third occurance or could that field be missing from that array?

Comment: Show us what you have tried to do so far, it gives us somewhere tostart from and tells us what database API you are using

Comment: A slight aside - if the number of values is user-defined, how will this work with your table - it must have a set number of columns. Are you sure your database is normalised properly? Obviously I don't know the logic behind the data but perhaps these values would be better in separate rows in a secondary table rather than in different columns in the master table?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: the option can be missing

Comment: @ADyson Not an aside, a very valid point. And it would make the storing of the information so much easier

Comment: To be more clear: the form can have x items, but every item has up to ten checkboxes and one option field. My table has fields for the itemID, ten for the checkbox values and one for the option value (plus some others that don't matter in this example). 

More or less I would now just need to find a way to get these numbers 1, 2, 17 (or whatever) to my $ItemID variable and write all the submitted rows into their own table rows.

Comment: What database API are you using? `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: PDO, but that's not the problem. :-)

I guess I struggle with getting the keys and values from multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Help at [PHP : foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach ( $items as $key => $values )
{
    // $key => 17 <= this the values you were looking for
    // $values => { [check_1] => 1, [check_3] => 1 }
    [...]
}
```

Init array:

```
$items = array(
    1 => array(
        "option" => 3,
        "check_1" => 1,
    ),
    2 => array(
        "option" => 2,
        "check_1" => 1,
    ),
    17 => array(
        "check_1" => 1,
        "check_3" => 1,
    ),
) ;
```

Parse array:

```
foreach( $items as $k1 => $a1 )
{ // should be escape for safety mysql_real_escape() or ...
    $dbCols = "item_id"; 
    $dbValues = $k1;
    foreach( $a1 as $k2 => $v2 )
    {
        $dbCols .= ",$k2"; 
        $dbValues .= ",$v2";
    }
    echo "INSERT INTO `table` ( $dbCols ) VALUES ( $dbValues );\n";
}
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( item_id,option,check_1 ) VALUES ( 1,3,1 );
INSERT INTO `table` ( item_id,option,check_1 ) VALUES ( 2,2,1 );
INSERT INTO `table` ( item_id,check_1,check_3 ) VALUES ( 17,1,1 );
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. 
This is especially important for questions that already have answers.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla _My biggest problem is to read out the Item IDs (1,2 and 17 in this case) and get it into variables_ => the problem is to get IDs values into variables ... isn't it ? `foreach` will help.
I can solve the problem, but that not the question. ;-)